# Extracting multiple array values from a ListBox item

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox

I've put three arrays into one line in a list box as such:

```
Listbox.Items.Add(array1[i] + "\t" + array2[i] + "\t" + array3[i]);
```

I want to be able to select one line, which would contain all 3 arrays, and
split the three values, one from each array, into 3 separate strings.
Right now I'm able to do:

```
string currentSelected = ListBox.GetItemText(ListBox.SelectedItem);
```

But this gives me all 3 array values in one string.

Comment: Note that an array is a collection of items. `int [] myArray = new int[5];` is an array of 5 `int` values. `myArray[0]` is the `int `value (the item) at position 0. Calling array items "arrays" in that scenario would be misleading. If `array1[i]`, etc. do resolve to arrays (rather than an array item), you won't be able to get them back from the string value.

Comment: Have you tried `string[] values = currentSelected.Split('\t');` ?

Comment: @BrianRogers Okay I got that working, thank you so much. I was so stumped I created an account for this. I was able to use what you gave me to split them up and define each string as values[0] to 2, thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_Char_System_StringSplitOptions_) method to do what you want:

```
string currentSelected = ListBox.GetItemText(ListBox.SelectedItem);
string[] values = currentSelected.Split('\t');
```

Comment: 'string[] values = ListBox.GetItemText(ListBox.SelectedItem).Split('\t'); ' Then was able to do 'TextBox.Text = values[0];' Up to 2, this worked, thank you.

Comment: No problem; glad I was able to help.